# can't connect to mongodb running on google cloud

Tags: mongodb, google-compute-engine

I entered the following command

```
mongo mongodb://<external_IP>:27017/myappdatabase
```

to connect to my remote database running on the google cloud platform. 
I'm getting the following error:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Connection Error here seems to suggest that the either the firewall on GCE [networking section] or the firewall on the host for accessing port 27017 is not enabled.

You will need to enable access for port 27017 for your client server IP.